# check kubernetes node\cluster resource before creating kubernetes resources

Tags: docker, kubernetes

on kubernetes, one can blindly create a resource (such as deployment, service, pods, etc.). the resouce will be created only if there are enough system resources on the kubernetes nodes\cluster.

1. how does one check that there are enough node resources before creating kubernetes resources (check whether a scale-out and\or scale-up are required)?
2. what is the best practice to check and asses that the kubernetes cluster can sustain a newly created resource before the resource is created (without doing any manual calculations)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for in (1) is possible with a [custom admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) - but I personally think that is too complex and not a great idea from the user experience point of view.

What would be ideal is that once a resource is created - and if the scheduler sees that there are not enough resources - then the cluster is autoscaled. This is possible with [Kubernetes Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) or [Escalator](https://github.com/atlassian/escalator). Both of them allow scaling cluster based on certain conditions - but are suited for different use cases.

You can find detailed information on how does the autoscaler adds nodes when it sees that a pod could be not be scheduled [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-up-work)

Comment: thank you but it doesn't fully answer my questions. besides, although you offered autoscaling, i wans not talking abou it. yet,  i do not want to have autoscaling configured, as it might inflate my bill because of missed configured kubernetes resource.

Comment: The autoscaler can scale up but also scale down when not used. So ideally configured autoscaler will keep cluster size in line with the resource needs. I don't think it will just increase cost - it will also help you reduce it